# NumberFormatter::ORDINAL giving me garbage

Tags: php, unicode, icu, ordinal, numberformatter

I'm trying to use the NumberFormatter class in PHP and I'm having problems with the ORDINAL format.  I've tried a couple other formats without a problem.  But when I use ORDINAL I just get garbage.  Choosing a different locale seems to give me different garbage.

```
$round = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
echo $round->format(6);
```

I would expect the output to be "6th" but instead I get "6áµ—Ê°".

Comment: Why don't you just ask the author of that class?

Answer (score 2):

That "garbage" on the end is some Unicode encoding of a superscript "th" symbol.  There are special symbols for superscript letters (although they are not commonly used), and NumberFormatter is using them.  The relevant rule file in ICU is http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/source/data/rbnf/en.txt.